# Decorate StreamReader and replace read text

Tags: c#, stream

I have a Stream that I want to replace the text on the fly when using the stream by a XmlSerializer. The initial stream should remain unchanged.

I tried to override Read method on StreamReader but I am a bit struggled :

```
public class ConfigHookReader : StreamReader
{
    public ConfigHookReader(Stream stream)
        : base(stream)
    {
    }

    public override int Read(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        var stringValue = new string(buffer);
        var replacedString = stringValue.Replace('A', 'B');
        var newBuffer = replacedString.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
        {
            buffer[i] = newBuffer[i];
        }

        return base.Read(buffer, index, count);
    }
}


[Test]
public void ReplaceIsWorking()
{
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DummyClass));
    var initialText = @"<DummyClass SomeString=""ABC""></DummyClass>";
    using (TextReader reader = new ConfigHookReader(new MemoryStream(initialText.Select(Convert.ToByte).ToArray())))
    {
        var instance = (DummyClass)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        Assert.AreEqual("AAC", instance.SomeString);//this si failing, SomeString = ABC
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to replace more than single characters by single characters, this gets quite complicated, because you will need to buffer read data over multiple calls -- so I hope all you're using this for is filtering/replacing an individual problematic character.

Comment: @JeroenMostert actually, yes target is to replace strings of any lenght...

Comment: Then you have your work cut out for you. Consider the scenario where you recognize `wordToReplace`, but `index + count` don't give you enough room to replace it with `wordToReplaceThatIsLonger`. If you are not dealing with multi-gigabyte strings where this on-the-fly replacing is necessary to avoid memory issues, consider a simpler wrapping strategy where your `TextReader` wraps (not overrides) another `TextReader` to first read all text, replace it, and delegates the rest of the work to a [`StringReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.stringreader).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be I am totally wrong... But the char-array passed to the read-function will be filled by the function so it is initally empty (or the content will be overwritten). The replace-function cannot work since the array is not filled when you walk through the array...
So read the data from the stream first and then replace the content. And if you're just replacing single character skip the string creation for performance reason'... **untested** since i have no IDE availiable here.

```
public class ConfigHookReader : StreamReader
{
    public override int Read(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        var read = base.Read(buffer, index, count);

        // EDIT (original) for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
        for (int i = 0; i < read; i++)
        {
            if (buffer[i] == 'A')
                buffer[i] = 'B';
        }

        return read;
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably only need to loop up to `read` characters (i.e., `i < read`).

Comment: Yes indeed, it is working. The use of the string is because I actually want to replace string of any lenght and what easier as a first step.